# workbooks.open w/ direct path doesn't work, but with HTML id workaround it does, why?

Tags: javascript, excel, path

I have been trying everything for days to figure this out and it's driving me crazy. I'm trying to read in excel data using HTML and JavaScript.

When I do the following, nothing works

```javascript
function getExcelData() {
    var ex;
    try {
      ex = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Your browser does not support the Activex object.\nPlease switch to Internet Explorer.');
      return false;
    }
    ex.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.xlsx");
    var eSheet = ex.Worksheets("Sheet2");
```

But when I do the same thing, only add multiple layers of code that I don't need/want, it does work.

```javascript
function _get(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function getExcelData() {
    var filePath = _get('filePath');

    var ex;
    try {
      ex = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Your browser does not support the Activex object.\nPlease switch to Internet Explorer.');
      return false;
    }
    ex.Workbooks.Open(filePath.value);
    var eSheet = ex.Worksheets("Sheet2");


<INPUT TYPE="hidden" ID="filePath" value="C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.xlsx" hidden="true">
```

I've checked, filePath.value is the exact same thing as "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.xlsx" and online every example I find on how to upload data from excel all put the file path directly into Workbooks.Open, so why doesn't that work for me and why does this workaround work instead? Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you need to escape any backslashes in a string literal:

```
ex.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test.xlsx");
```

When the value is coming from the input there's no need to escape the slashes